# POST http://localhost:9091/xxxx 400 (Bad Request) on trying send json form data from client side to server side using react

Tags: reactjs, json, forms

I'm getting this error when I'm trying to send json form data from client side to server side. I'm using react for frontend and Golang for server side coding. This is how I've written my handle submit method

```
const response = await fetch('http://localhost:9091/rewardAdmin/v1/rewardRule/createRewardInfo', {
      method: 'POST',
      mode: 'no-cors',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' },
      body: JSON.stringify(formData.formData),
    });
```

I've tried to change the content type to 'application/json' as well and it didn't work.

This is my backend code.

```
func (rc *RewardAdminController) CreateRewardInfo(ctx echo.Context) error {
    var rewardInfo rewardInfo.RewardInfoRequest
    if err := ctx.Bind(&rewardInfo); err != nil {
        return ctx.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, err.Error())
    }
    result, err := rc.RewardRuleService.CreateRewardInfo(rewardInfo)
    if err != nil {
        return ctx.JSON(http.StatusBadGateway, err.Error())
    }
    return ctx.JSON(http.StatusOK, result)
}
```

Does anyone have a solution to this?

To send the json data from the form filled to my REST API written in golang

Comment: The content type should def be application/json. Without seeing your backend code though, we'll not be able to help you.

Comment: It would help if you provide abit more code such as the actual form, the backend code, the handlers, etc. For example, when sending a form directly, in certain cases you must set the enctype to "multipart/form-data". Also, when setting the headers, you will need other headers such as Accept: "application/json" or many others. When you look at a standard request in your browser you'll find quite a few other headers. But without a more complete sample of your code, we can only guess at what is wrong as many things can cause a 400 error.